# Dotnetnuke captcha control customization

Tags: dotnetnuke, captcha, dotnetnuke-module

is there any way to customize Dotnetnuke captcha control? I want to change background and text color of the captcha image. I am using dnn 4.xx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly sure that there is not a way to adjust the DNN CAPTCHA control in an extensible way (i.e. without changing core DNN code).

If you're using the CAPTCHA control in your own module, you may have some options, but changing it where the framework uses it (during the registration and/or login process) won't be customizable, so far as I know.

Comment: Ok thanks for answer, I will use another captcha control then.